# SQL Server : restrict database access only to specific user login

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, ddos

I have an odd situation where I ran this query to see how many connections are opened towards my database, and I found out this:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as 'Number Of Connections',
    loginame as LoginName
FROM 
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

The last user with 26 opened connections i the one that I've set to access the database via WEB.

The odd thing is this user that has 128 opened connections, and I'm not even sure if this is a user since the login name is just a plain empty string??

Another worrying thing is that I've checked and when all of these connections are opened towards my database the CPU processor goes up to 100%

Here is the result of the query and the odd connection towards my DB is marked with red color:

[image]

My question here is:

How can I restrict all outer access to my database except for a specific user that I have defined to be able to access through the DB ?

Can someone help me out with this ?

@RBarryYoung here are the result of the query:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPNwK6PkqAcgPjSp5biYlPmoKhbmKD9fl8nMmRElYPE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: only users you have explicitly granted permissions to (hopefully via roles and AD groups) have access. Not sure what your question is

Comment: @MitchWheat but what is this user, it's just an empty string, It's not even a user? I can't see the user name of the user accessing the DB ?

Comment: largely irrelevant if you have locked down security as I mentioned in previous comment...otherwise how is anyone supposed to help you with an empty string?...State how your security is set up...Also, do you really prefix database names with "db_"?

Comment: @MitchWheat So I've created a user which is attached to the database that I have in my mssql management studio. (via the security node => users node -mssql login). I don't think I've setup anything via AD groups?

Comment: Look at the full sysprocesses and see what those processes look like.  Add this information to your post. In particular, see if their SPIDs match up to any other processes, or if their ECIDs are set.

Comment: @RBarryYoung what kind of query would I have to run to see this information ?

Comment: `select * from sys.sysprocesses`

Comment: @RBarryYoung Okay done, one sec I will post results

Comment: @RBarryYoung Terribly sorry for delay, I had to upload the spreadsheet on google docs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPNwK6PkqAcgPjSp5biYlPmoKhbmKD9fl8nMmRElYPE/edit?usp=sharing

Could please take a look at it ?

Comment: Ok, yeah.  Notice how they all have an ECID > 0, and they share the same SPID as some other (base) process with ECID =0 that has a username?  Those are just worker threads thrown off by the base process, sysprocesses just has a weird way of showing them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Okay what does that means in my case? The CPU goes all the way up to 100% when these things appear... Is there any way to shut them off ? =(

Comment: No, this is just load being generated by the query (or action) being run by the base process of each SPID.  You would need to tune those queries/actions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung ah so it's the queries that I have are what's causing the issues right ? I need to tweak them right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.